# Custom field not working in search

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, search

I have a search page set up with a shortcode like this:

[civicrm component="profile" gid="18" mode="search" hijack="0"]

Everything seems to be working except that searching on a custom data field, "Certification," generally isn't working.

None of the other search fields are custom fields. Don't know if that relates to the problem.

------ new material below, added in response to comments -----

"Certification" is a text field and is set to "Searchable."

Some examples of content for the "Certification" field are shown below. I would expect that I could search on any string within any of these (e.g. `Curr` or `Curriculum` or `Teac` or `Teacher`). None of those work. Even searching on a complete entry like `Coach, Trainer/Teacher, Curriculum Instructor` doesn't work. The only one I've found that works is `Coach` -- I'm guessing because that is a complete entry with no commas? Perhaps the commas are causing the problem?

I'm realizing that this data was imported into a CiviCRM text field from a multiple-select field in another database. There were four options in the other database: `Coach`, `Trainer/Teacher`, `Curriculum Instructor`, and `Mediator`. I'm thinking I need to change or move this into a multiple-select field in CiviCRM. Not sure what the best/easiest way to do that is.

[image: certification examples]

Wordpress 4.7.5 CiviCRM 4.7.17

Comment: Please confirm that your Custom Field is set to be Searchable

Comment: Also give us a hint as to what value in 'certification' should deliver a result

Comment: Actually found one search that works.  See material added at the end of the post.

Comment: have you tried searching for coac%? seems to work for me. % is the wildcard character to use in civicrm searching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend changing the certification field into a multi-select. That way the search field will be a drop down and much easier for the end user. I had to do this recently. Here are the steps I took:

- Create a new multi select custom field.
- Make sure the values match the entries from the previous field to avoid errors in the next step.
- Export the records with the current custom field. Make sure to include the contact ID
- Now do a import updating the new custom field with the data from the old one.

These are the steps I took recently. Looks like you only have about 100 records in this group so it should work fine.

Comment: So export and import I do with SQL commands?

Comment: Okay, I get it.  Not SQL. I used CiviCRM contact export and import.  And it worked brilliantly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

% is the wildcard character to use in civicrm searching. searching for coac%? seems to work for me.